# Android: BroadCastEvent not recieved when media files added/removed/edited for MTP devices

Tags: android

I need to handle events when MediaStore is changed over MTP. I already have a receiver for android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED action, but it is useful only for Universal Mass Storage(UMS). The scanner is not launched over MTP, because the MTP changes the MediaStore database directly.

This is handled in native gallery properly.
Please would you be so kind and help me how to detect this events. Thank you very much for any help!